# Use Ajax to load full node including comments and comment form

Tags: 7, ajax, nodes

I tried to use [Ajax links API Module](http://drupal.org/project/ajax_links_api), nice module it even replace url when loading page but it works so slowly... I can wait page loading even for few minutes. I found another solution [seanbuscay.com](http://seanbuscay.com/ajax-reader-demo) it works better but it doesn't load comments and comment form. I would like to load full node including comments (create view reference field with related comments didn't help).

I found some similar topics

[Ajax via Jquery and attach behaviors](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/42669/ajax-via-jquery-and-attach-behaviors)

[Load and interact with a node comments from their related node](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/16674/drupal-7-ajax-to-load-interact-with-one-nodes-comments-from-its-related-node)

Is it the best solution for Drupal 7 t use drupal.attach.behaviours?

Have anybody experience with loading full nodes with comments via ajax?

Comment: detail your question, where you want to load this node - in popup window of your site or android apps or somewhere else?

Comment: just in another div of the page

Answer (score 1):

This modules contains a lot of extra code for your case and probably make too much unnecessary actions. You should to make a little script to make [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) that make request, insert your node with comments in  and connect it to your theme. This modules made request by Query.ajax too.

Less code - faster action and may the force be with you.